# MUI V5 styled(Typography) variant not work

Tags: material-ui, variant, typography

Right now the Typography variant is inline as below:

```
<Typography variant="h6">
  Any text
</Typography>
```

If the styled Typography writen as below, the **variant** does not actually take effect. May I ask why it does not work? How the code should be looks like? Thanks.

```
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  variant: theme.typography.h6,
}));

<StyledTypography>
  Any text
</StyledTypography>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to use the `h6` variant, pass it in as a prop. `variant` is not a valid parameter.

```js
<Typography variant="h6">

</Typography>
```

You can also pass a prop into the styled component.

```js
<StyledTypography variant="h6">
  
</StyledTypography>
```

`theme.typography.h6` is an object that contains a variety of things, for example, `lineHeight`, `fontWeight` that sort of stuff. It isn't something you can just pass like that as a styling property.

You can spread this object into a styled component to achieve the result you want, but again, not worth it, just use variant as a prop.

```js
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.h6 // Don't do this.
}));

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <StyledTypography>
      Just use normal Typography
    </StyledTypography>
  );
}
```

Here's a simple working example of what I'm describing: https://codesandbox.io/s/variant-as-styled-parameter-zd975r?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

first check your import if the styled is from @mui/materials/styles you may run into some issue if you import it thru styled-components.

Comment: wrong path, the correct one is '@mui/material/styles'

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here :
https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

You can access the data with 
${props => props.key}

so,

change

```
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  variant: theme.typography.h6,
}));
```

to

```
const StyledTypography = styled.div`
variant: ${props => props.variant}
`
```

and then access your object with proper keys,

`props.variant.theme.typography.h6`, for example.

Comment: Their question was related to why it wasn't working using MUI styled components. Your solution doesn't address this.